# conda activate does not accept more than one argument:

Tags: python-3.x, linux, anaconda

I have conda 4.8.4, on my Linux server and still see this issue.
$ /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.posix activate taking the arguments $1 $2 $3 $4 passed to the bash script. These args are for the python script I'm calling within the .sh script.

```
source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda init

echo "Calling myscript.py"

python3 ./myscript.py $1 $2 $3 $4
```

Answer (score 1):

For pathnames that have spaces, the pathnames should be wrapped in quotes. Example:

"C:\Users\User\Documents\CondaFiles\env\my new environment"

Answer (score 0):

using `source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate base` should resolve the issue

see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2965
(was having the same problem and this worked for me)